# opendkim-testkey: keys do not match

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, email-server, opendkim

How do you produce the 'default._domainkey.drpedroazevedo.com' file? I deleted mine because my key expired and opendkim-keygen did not produce a new one as expected.

```
    mlr01 keys # opendkim-testkey -d drpedroazevedo.com -s default -vvv -k /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private -x /etc/opendkim/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private: WARNING: unsafe permissions
opendkim-testkey: key loaded from /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.drpedroazevedo.com'
opendkim-testkey: keys do not match
```

Comment: what opendkim version that you have?

Comment: @masegaloeh I started with 2.8.4 and now on  2.9.2-r1, Gentoo portage.  Updated info  ->  https://bpaste.net/show/4a63b71ec9c3

Comment: cp /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private /etc/opendkim/default.private fixed it  o.0

Comment: If you have a solution, you can always answer your own question by posting it in answer section :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like OpenDKIM was mistakenly looking private key in another directory. Running this command

```
cp /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private /etc/opendkim/default.private
```

magically fixed it o.0. I'm not sure why this is happened